# Sens du mot « pissette »

Tags: expressions

Bonjour

Ce matin j'ai vu sur une vieille affiche de France quelque chose d'écrit sur un menu d'un restaurant qui a piqué ma curiosité; il y a le terme « pissette » écrit dessus. (En haut a gauche sur le tableau noir dans la photo).

Je suis pas mal sure que le terme ne veut pas dire celui que je pense, alors je me demandais si c'était une expression pour dire une "pinte" en exemple ou une "louche", ou juste un attrape-oeil.

Voici l'extrait ou j'ai vu cela;

"Bert Hardy.
Restaurant La Grenouille  1952  #Paris"

https://twitter.com/ParisAMDParis/status/1451213758647476227?s=20

[image]

Merci

Comment: Le terme auquel tu penses est, il me semble, strictement Québécois, donc pour les autres francophones au Québec peux-tu ajouter qu'une pissette c'est un pénis (si c'est bien à ça que tu penses  !)

Comment: @None oh, oui alors effectivement, mais j'ai failli marquer que l'affiche n'était pas au moulin rouge tout de meme, ou une allusion comme cela, mais je n'ai pas oser le marquer

Comment: Ce [restaurant](http://guilainedepis.blogspirit.com/media/01/01/2203464787.png) existe encore (known today as Roger la Grenouille). Si un parisien de la liste y faisait un tour peut-être on pourrait peut-être lui expliquer ce mot mystérieux. [Une autre photo du menu sur l'ardoise](https://www.gettyimages.ch/detail/nachrichtenfoto/in-the-restaurant-roger-la-grenouille-28-rue-des-nachrichtenfoto/526698104?language=fr) (1950). merci @jlliagre (Pour le rapprochement, je ne suggère pas que tu y ailles).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mystère résolu !

Il s'agit de la direction des toilettes.

La photo de 1950 dont le [lien](https://www.gettyimages.ch/detail/nachrichtenfoto/in-the-restaurant-roger-la-grenouille-28-rue-des-nachrichtenfoto/526698104?language=fr) a été fourni par @None montre l'inscription « **Pipi Room** » avec une flèche vers la gauche qui ne laisse aucun doute sur la signification de « **Pissette** »...

[image]

Comment: WoW, merci à toi et @None pour avoir trouvé cela ! Un vrai travail de détective :) Je comprend mieux l’utilisation :)

Comment: Excellent. Même sur la première photo, il y a une forme de flêche, difficile à discerner.

Answer (score 1):

**Première idée :**
Il existe une espèce de crevette dont le nom courant est pissette (ou chevrette) et le nom scientifique *Xiphocaris elongata* ; on la trouve dans les Caraïbes. Elle est mentionnée dans cet *[Arrêté](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/jorf/id/JORFTEXT000000588886) du 12 novembre 2001 fixant la liste des espèces de poissons et de crustacés représentés dans les cours d'eau et les plans d'eau de la Martinique*.

Elle vit en eau douce et on s'en sert parfois comme ornement dans les aquariums. On en trouvera une description partielle dans [cette page](http://www.martinique.developpement-durable.gouv.fr/crustaces-terrestres-et-d-eau-douce-a1494.html) de la DEAL de la Martinique. Et une image sur [ce site](https://www.fishfish.fr/crustace/xiphocaris-elongata) pour aquariophiles car elle s'adapte parfaitement à la vie en aquarium.
Je ne sais pas si elle était consommée de façon courante, mais de nos jours de toutes façons les eaux dans lesquelles vit cette espèce étant encore polluées par [le chlordécone](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlord%C3%A9cone)<sup>1</sup> la pêche en est interdite.

Cependant je suis fort étonnée de voir un nom d'espèces de crevettes plutôt que « crevettes » sur un menu et, autant je suis sûre de moi sur l'existence de l'animal en question, autant je ne garantis pas que c'est de ça qu'il s'agit sur ce menu !

**Deuxième idée encore plus farfelue :**
Une pissette, en plus d'être un genre de bouteille à laver dont on se sert en laboratoire, s'emploie aussi pour désigner un filet d'eau, on pourrait extrapoler que c'est mis ici pour « eau » (qui serait servie en carafe) mais ça me semble un peu tiré par les cheveux.

**Troisième idée tout autant farfelue :**
Après avoir vu sur le site d'un vignoble un vin appelé *agace-pissette* avec la précision :

> Agace Pissette (vocable poétique français du 17ème siècle)

je me dis que peut-être il est fait référence à un apéritif maison (et offert par la maison). Mais je n'ai jamais rencontré cette expression, ni ne l'ai trouvée   dans mes recherches

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> La France n'a interdit l'utilisation du chlordécone en Martinique et en Guadeloupe qu'en 1993.</sup>

Comment: Le problème c'est qu'on dirait un titre. Et puis, à cette date-là, je ne pense pas qu'on importait, par avion, des crevettes des départements d'outre mer (Caraïbes).

Comment: @Lambie J'ai d'abord pensé que c'était un titre parce que c'est écrit plus gros, mais ensuite je me suis dit que c'était dans la même colonne que les poissons et escargots - les viandes étant ailleurs. Pour ce qui est de l'importation ce n'est pas un problème vu qu'il parait que que ça s'adapte bien dans tout aquarium, ça ne m'a pas gêne pas. Vraiment le plus gênant dans cette interprétation est pourquoi ne pas dire tout simplement crevettes.

Comment: En tout cas, il fallait les transporter, morts ou vivants. Et je doute fort qu'en 1952, toujours l'après guerre en quelque sorte, on faisait des choses pareilles. Surtout, pour le bistro coin. Cette photo m'a choquée parce qu'elle me rappelle une expérience horrible que j'ai eu dans un restau à Lyon....

Comment: @Lambie En 1952 je vivais dans le sud de la France et on mangeait toutes sortes de choses, des crevettes il y en avait, ça n'est pas un problème. On a mis fin aux restrictions en France en janvier 1949, plus de tickets de rationnement (beaucoup plus tard en GB).

Comment: It doesn't matter what I say, I will be downvoted. Good luck! Just because there are no rationing cards doesn't mean "exotic foods" were all over the place. especially in a restaurant like that. If this just means crevettes, fine. But there does not seem to be any way to check that.

Comment: @Lambie In order to check we'd have to ask the people who put up that slate, wouldn't we? I did say the idea was farfelue and « je ne garantis pas que c'est de ça qu'il s'agit  ».  So I don't understand what you're getting at.  What do you mean "like that" ?  The items on the menu are dishes that people would normally eat, at home for some,  when eating out for others. And in those days people ate a lot more meat than now and it was comparatively less expensive than now.

Comment: A restaurant like that: un bistro du coin dans un quartier populaire. Not un restaurant quatre ou cinq étoiles dans un beau quartier.

Comment: @Lambie Nothing on that menu is fancy or exotic. (Pineapple or lychees would have been exotic - at least not canned)   Food arrived daily to the Halles in Paris and there were lots of restaurants where workers could eat eat well, and cheap. You might have the wrong idea of Paris at the time, or  of what people ate in those days... Have you read  *Le ventre de Paris* ? Much what is described as far as the town and the food is concerned is still valid until the 60s.

Comment: I am not convinced that these crevettes, called pissettes in Martinique and Guadaloupe are what is on that menu. Maybe it is. Because it collocates as exotic and all the other items on the list are just typical French lunch or dinner fare...

Comment: @Lambie  As I said in my answer I'm not convinced either (what do you think *je suis fort étonnée* means?)  - we agree on that. I disagree with you when you say crevettes in the 50s were fancy food for un restaurant quatre ou cinq étoiles. That 's not the case.

Comment: @Lambie Pas vraiment le bistro du coin ou ton boui-boui lyonnais. Ce restaurant du Quartier latin était fréquenté par Picasso, Saint Exupéry, Galabru, Mistinguett et a même reçu le pape Jean XXIII et *Queen Mum*. Pas du genre qui empoisonne ses clients.

Comment: Not crevettes. Pissettes de la **Martinique ou de la Gaudeloupe**.  If that is what this is. It is most definitely "exotiques" for the time and place.

Comment: @Lambie Coming form a fishtank in the restaurant I really doubt they could be called exotic, if this was indeed crevettes on that menu (I said *je ne garantis pas que c'est de ça qu'il s'agit sur ce menu *. I really don't get your point as hard as I try to.

Comment: @jlliagre I've looked at photos of Roger La Grenouille from around that time and you're absolutely right, it definitely is Roger La Grenouille. It did not look like a boui-boui on the photo posted by the OP, and now we can say it definitely it isn't, wasn't even at the time. We must admit it's a lot more fancy now than it was then!

Comment: Ce *pissette* me laisse perplexe. Il n'y a pas rien d'associé alors que tous le reste à un prix bien indiqué. Il n'y a pas de fautes d'orthographe dans le reste de la carte (même pas en anglais avec *mutton chop* et *steack* est accepté), on peut donc difficilement imaginer que *pissette* en soit une. Peut-être y a-t-il un rapport avec le mode de conservation, le fournisseur, la moindre disponibilité des plats situés dessous, la saison, mais ça n'explique pas ce mot étrange. Je ne pense pas non plus que Pie VII soit pour quelque chose à l'affaire ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre Je penche pour un mot « maison », quel qu'en soit le sens, que seuls les habitués comprendraient.  Les escargots et les cuisses de grenouilles ça se sert (peut se servir) en entrée, j'ai cherché de ce côté là. Mais je ne connais pas d'autre sens du mot pissette que les deux que je donne et comme je disais ça me semble farfelu. J'avais aussi pensé à un jeu de mot autour d'agace-pissette (un apéro maison qui agacerait la pissette autrement qu'au Québec) mais ça me semblait peu compatible avec 1952.

Comment: Ah oui, plutôt outré: de l'eau en carafe annoncée en lettres capitales et souligné tel un titre …

Comment: Il y a aussi la pissette pour doser le pastis, mais je ne vois pas trop ce qu'elle ferait là.

Comment: @jlliagre ces dossettes c'est le même principe que les pissettes de labo. Si on eut en rester sur la photo et pas le mot, peut-être que ce n'est pas pissette qui est écrit...

Comment: peut-être CAISSETTE ou CAISSE ...